# Controller extension method without this

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I would like to create controller extension method. What I got so far is below

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    this.ExtensionMethod();
    return View();
}

public static void ExtensionMethod(this Controller controller)
{

}
```

What I don't like is that ExtensionMethod must be called with `this` keyword. Is it possible to get rid of `this`?

Comment: Why don't you make a regular method instead of an extension method ?

Comment: @Tomas Indeed, if you are able to edit the type itself why not make a normal method? Extension methods are simply sugar to extend locked types.

Comment: Because this method will be helper and I would like to embed in into Controller class. I don't want to write New MyHelperClass().ExtensionMethod everytime I would use method.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No.

It is the `this` keyword that makes the method an extension method. Without it, it's just a static method.

Edit: Sorry, I misread the question. There are two `this` keywords: one in the extension method, and one used to call it.

The reason you need the `this` keyword when you call it is that you need to specify the object that is being extended. C# doesn't automatically resolve local method calls to extension methods unless you specify the `this` keyword.

Comment: He means the call of the method from the Controller itself: this.ExtensionMethod(). He wants to avoid it there.

Comment: Well either way, an extension method is also just a static method. Extension methods just look nicer in IntelliSense :-)

Comment: he asked about the call `this.ExtensionMethod();` not about declaration

Comment: I have asked about method call with keyword this. I know that to get extension method this keyword must be in method declaration.

Comment: Yeah, I caught that almost as soon as I posted the answer. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3):

That's how it is. You can't do anything against it.

You may think about putting it into a base class - which is mostly not a great idea (because it blows up the base class).

Comment: @x2: Or sugar is not sweet enough.

Answer (score 2):

You can use it like.

```
this.ExtensionMethod();
```

or

```
ExtenstionClassName.ExtensionMethod(this);
```

Your choice...